# not scrolling up when keypad appears in Framelayout

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext

I am Using Framelayout.It contains number of editexts.It is not scrolling up when keypad appears.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tab1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F6F6F6">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fi_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:text="First Name"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fir_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.7"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/midname"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:text="Middle Name"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mid_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.7"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"


            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:text="Last Name"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/las_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.7"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"


            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:text="Date Of Birth"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dob"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.7"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:onClick="cal"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:text="Age"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/age"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.7"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"


            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:text="Gender"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/gen"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.7"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:onClick="gen"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"


            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:text="Blood Group"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/bgroup"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.7"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:onClick="bgu"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"


            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:text="Education"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/edu"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.7"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:onClick="edu"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"


            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:text="Current Education"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/c_edu"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.7"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:onClick="cedu"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"


            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:text="Profession"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/profes"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.7"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:onClick="pro"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"


            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:text="Marital Status"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/mrg"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.7"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:onClick="mrg"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:text="Father's name"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fath_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.7"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:text="Father's village"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fathers_village"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.7"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:text="Phone Number 1"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/pnumber1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.7"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:text="Phone Number 2"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/pnumber2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.7"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"

                android:text="Email"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.7"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:text="Other Details"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/other_details"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.7"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I tried this following solution .But it is not working for me.

I am using this in `oncreateView` method `getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);`

Any answers will help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this property in your manifest activity :

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"

Answer (score 0):

Define the following attribute in  of AndroidManifest.xml.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

or use

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in your manifest.

Add this in activity attribute. Only this single line works well for me to click on next button of edittext take me to next edittext field and scroll the form up. So try this

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: Please can you share me your xml part only so may be i will help you properly by testing that on my end

Comment: I have checked it ... It works fine for me.. but please tell are you testing it in emulator or in real device

Comment: i am checking in real device